# Curly brackets in gedit on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gedit

i have gedit 2.30.2 installed  (Latest build) and Mac OSX 10.6.5 .
I cannot get it to write a curly bracket with  +  + "8" .
On Ubuntu, no problem, on XCode no problem, but gedit won't let me write a curly bracket...
I searched on google a lot and found everytime the same answer: use  +  + "8" ....
PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite late, I know, but I think, what you want is actually this.

right-click on text window of gedit, scroll down to "Input Method" in the contextual menu, and select "Multipress". You probably have "Simple" selected, as that is the default.

I was mad with disbelief when I could not type #.

Comment: Well the snippets seemed a bit hard to do, cuz nothing happened after i configured it. Anyway, saw yours, perfect solution. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's quite easy to work arround.
Activate the Snippets plugin in gedit's options. 
And create a snippet for the most important characters.

Ah, after years of searching I hope I found my text editor of choice ;)

Comment: This might sound like a retarded workaround, but it's actually much simpler than the X11 route, and pretty much solves the problem entirely. Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question should properly belong to serverfault, but in some sense it's about the programming in GTK+, so I'll answer here.

Which language environment do you set in System Preferences? GTK+ implemented on OS X on top of Cocoa has had a problem around the keyboard input if the system is not in the English mode with an English keyboard.

You will have a better luck if you use gedit via X11 on OS X.